# If key of a object contains a word

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I've got a object like this:

```
{"status":200, 
"success":true, 
"result": [ {"Description":"", "Year":"", "Price/STK":"", "Main Cat":"Fruits"} ]
}
```

I have distinct lists I need to use, and the Price key can be: Price/STK, Price/Box, Price/Btl or Price.

I know I can get the value using, for example, data.result['Price/STK'], but I don't want to check every key, I'd like to search for the price and just use.

How would I determine if a word ('Price*', for example) is part of a key and get that value?

Comment: You'll have to loop through the keys and check each one in turn to see if it starts with price, or use lodash _.findKey(obj, function(key) { return _.startsWith('Price')})

Comment: I don't think there's  a way to achieve your goal without looping through every key. May I know why don't you want to check each key?

Comment: Well, I just want to optimize the way to get values and maybe we can find a better way to do it....

Comment: You can't really "optimize" this; there's no native method that allows for anything better than iteration through the key values. Libraries can make the code *shorter*, but that's only because they're hiding the inevitable iteration.

Comment: Maybe you should change your structure so there's a single element `Price`, whose value is an object containing a `STK` or `Box` or `Btl` property.

Comment: I can't change, It's not mine :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this, you have to iterate and check each key.

You could just create a convenient function :

```
function matchKey(objectToSearch, keyToFind) {
    for (var k in objectToSearch) {
        if ( k.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyToFind.toLowerCase()) !== -1) 
            return objectToSearch[k];
    }
    return null;
}

matchKey({year : 2015, "Price/STK" : "value"}, "price"); // returns "value"
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bckrt8hg/)

Comment: There are built–in iterators though, and the OP wants the value of a property matching `/^Price/`, not exact match.

Comment: You don't 'have' to iterate, you could always use a library that does it for you and keeps your code a lot cleaner. I know this is still iterating, but 'you' don't 'have to' write iterator code for this.

Comment: @RobG - what built–in iterators do you suggest for an object like this ?

Comment: @EngineerDollery - True, there are libraries, but why don't you just post an answer stating that the OP should include jQuery, underscore or lodash, and see how that works out for you ?

Comment: @adeno—*some* would be good as it stops at the first match. You could fix your loop using `== 0` instead of `!= -1` but it should include a *hasOwnProperty* test.

Comment: Maybe you can give another example using that method? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RobG - Using `Array.some` would require an array, which would require using `Object.keys`, which isn't really needed here, and would be much slower, as my loop also stops at the first match. As for "fixing" the loop, I intentionally used `!== -1` because the OP was asking for *"How would I determine if a word is part of a key"*, and the title says *"contains"*, it said nothing about *"starts with"* !

Comment: @adeneo—I used to prefer loops as they're easy to understand and were faster than iterators. But many argue for iterators as they provide greater encapsulation of the loop body and in recent browsers they're [*at least as fast*](http://jsperf.com/iterator-vs-loop-2015-10-22) as loops. *some* and *every* are suitable because (like your loop) they can stop early whereas other iterators like *forEach* don't. So there is no good reason not to use *Object.keys* with an iterator as it obviates a *hasOwnProperty* test and provides greater robustness for no additional effort.

Comment: Then how to get "Price/STK" value in same logic ?

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this problem easily using lodash (or underscore)

```
_.findKey(obj, function(key) { return _.startsWith(key, 'Price')})
```

This finds the first key that starts with price.

Comment: I like your solution, any way to do it using angularjs?

Comment: not really, that's a gui library and isn't really for this sort of thing, but you can use both together if that's your worry

Comment: I think that should be `_.startsWith(key, 'Price')`

Comment: Thanks @Pointy -- thats the problem with not testing one's code until it's in production ;)

Comment: @EngineerDollery how to find all keys that starts with Price?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the property names of an object using *Object.keys*, and then use *indexOf* to search for a value, but it does an exact match and doesn't take a regular expression as an argument.

So you have to loop over all the property names until you find the one you want. There are built–in iterators to help:

```js
var obj = {"status":200, 
  "success":true, 
  "result": [ {"Description":"desc", 
               "Year":"yr", 
               "Price/STK":"price/stk",
               "Main   Cat":"Fruits"}
            ]
};

function getValueLike(obj, prop){
  var re = new RegExp('^' + prop);
  var value;
  Object.keys(obj).some(function(prop) {
    if (re.test(prop)) {
      value = obj[prop];
      return true;
    }
  });
  return value;
}

document.write(getValueLike(obj.result[0], 'Price')); // price/stk
```

A version that uses *indexOf* on the property name might be faster and is a little less code:

```
function getValueLike(obj, prop){
  var value;
  Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
    if (key.indexOf(prop) == 0) {
      value = obj[key];
      return true;
    }
  });
  return value;
}
```

which can be reduced to:

```
function getValueLike(obj, prop, value){
  Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {return key.indexOf(prop) == 0 && ((value = obj[key]) || true)});
  return value;
}
```

which also allows a default value to be passed to *value*, but it's a little too obfuscated for me.

Using an arrow function:

```
function getValueLike(obj, prop, value){
  Object.keys(obj).some(key => key.indexOf(prop) == 0 && ((value = obj[key]) || true));
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the set of keys on the result array's object for "Price", and then return the value associated with that. I made a function for it as an example.

```js
function selectPrice(obj){
  return obj.result[0][
      Object.keys(obj.result[0]).filter(function(el){ 
          return el.indexOf("Price") > -1 
      })[0]
  ]
}

var data = {"status":200, 
"success":true, 
"result": [ {"Description":"", "Year":"", "Price/STK":"6", "Main Cat":"Fruits"} ]
};

document.write(selectPrice(data));
```

Comment: This fails if the object doesn't find a match in the keys.

Comment: @RobG - Or if the object doesn't contain a result. Or if the result has a populated array of objects and not just one single one. Or if the object is somehow malformed. Or if the wrong type of object is sent in. What happens if the Price is empty? All of these issues are up to the OP to manipulate with their business logic. In all honesty, *what should the business logic be if there is no price??* No one knows but them so imposing that logic makes no sense here, perhaps it should even cause an error.

Comment: It's up to the caller to provide suitable inputs, throwing an exception because of internal logic isn't a good strategy.

Comment: @RobG - You are overthinking and overengineering this scenario. OP didn't call for a function that searches an object with a json like structure for partial matches. It was very specific, and that is what is provided here. If it were as broad as you indicate, then it should be closed as the canonical. However, that isn't the case here.